# Load data from .ini crash my game! What can I do? c++

Tags: c++, file, crash, load, ini

Hello I am trying to create a script to save/load my custom Weapon Layout for my game.
The save function works fine, but if I want load the layout, it crash my game.
I know where the problem is, but idk how to fix these, so I need your knowledge!

```
void SaveWeaponsLayout()
{
    Ini wpLayout = (".\\Files\\Settings\\WeaponsLayout.ini");
    Log::Msg("Reading Data for WeaponsLayout.ini!");
    Player playerPed = PLAYER::PLAYER_PED_ID();
    if (!ENTITY::IS_ENTITY_DEAD(playerPed))
    {
        for (auto & wpID : weaponLayoutList)
        {
            Hash weapon = wpID.weaponHash;
            char * wpName = wpID.WeaponName;
            if (WEAPON::HAS_PED_GOT_WEAPON(playerPed, wpID.weaponHash, 0))
            {
                int weaponInHex = weapon;
                std::string weaponInHex_ = hexify< int >(weaponInHex);
                wpLayout.WriteString(weaponInHex_, wpName, "WEAPONHASH");
            }
            for (auto & wpCompID : weaponComponentList)
            {
                Hash weaponComp = wpCompID.weaponCompHash;
                char * wpCompName = wpCompID.weaponComponent;
                if (WEAPON::HAS_PED_GOT_WEAPON_COMPONENT(playerPed, wpID.weaponHash, wpCompID.weaponCompHash))
                {
                    int weaponCompInHex = weaponComp;
                    std::string weaponCompInHex_ = hexify< int >(weaponCompInHex);
                    wpLayout.WriteString(weaponCompInHex_, wpName, wpCompName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log::Msg("Files WeaponsLayout.ini created!");
    Notifications::MessageCentre6000("~p~Saved~s~: Weapons Layout");
}
```

The list where I get the Weapon Data from the game >>

```
static struct wpList
{
    __int64 weaponHash;
    char * WeaponName;
};
static std::vector<wpList> weaponLayoutList{
    //{ 0xA2719263, "Unarmed" },
{ 0xFBAB5776, "Parachute" },
{ 0x99B507EA, "Knife" },
{ 0x8BB05FD7, "Flashlight" },
{ 0xCD274149, "Battle Axe" },
{ 0x94117305, "Pool Cue" },
...
}; // 88x Weapons
```

The list where I get the Weapon Components Data from the game >>

```
static struct wpCompList
{
    unsigned int weaponCompHash;
    char * weaponComponent;
};

static std::vector<wpCompList> weaponComponentList{
    { 0x75414F30, "COMPONENT_AT_RAILCOVER_01" },
{ 0x0C164F53, "COMPONENT_AT_AR_AFGRIP" },
{ 0x359B7AAE, "COMPONENT_AT_PI_FLSH" },
{ 0x7BC4CDDC, "COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH" },
{ 0x9D2FBF29, "COMPONENT_AT_SCOPE_MACRO" },
...
}; // 551x Weapon Components
```

This is the WeaponsLayout.ini what I have saved!

```
[Micro SMG]
WEAPONHASH=0x13532244
COMPONENT_AT_PI_FLSH=0x359b7aae
COMPONENT_AT_AR_SUPP_02=0xa73d4664
COMPONENT_MICROSMG_CLIP_02=0x10e6ba2b
[Assault Rifle]
WEAPONHASH=0xbfefff6d
COMPONENT_ASSAULTRIFLE_CLIP_03=0xdbf0a53d
[Advanced Rifle]
WEAPONHASH=0xaf113f99
COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH=0x7bc4cddc
COMPONENT_ADVANCEDRIFLE_CLIP_01=0xfa8fa10f
[Pump Shotgun]
WEAPONHASH=0x1d073a89
COMPONENT_AT_AR_FLSH=0x7bc4cddc
COMPONENT_AT_SR_SUPP=0xe608b35e
COMPONENT_PUMPSHOTGUN_CLIP_01=0xd16f1438
COMPONENT_PUMPSHOTGUN_VARMOD_LOWRIDER=0xa2d79ddb
```

**...so now my script what make me problems, because it search in my file for all Weapons & Weapon Components!**

```
void LoadWeaponsLayout()
{
    Log::Msg("Files reading WeaponsLayout.ini!");
    Ini wpLayout = (".\\Files\\Settings\\WeaponsLayout.ini");
    Player playerPed = PLAYER::PLAYER_PED_ID();
    if (!ENTITY::IS_ENTITY_DEAD(playerPed))
    {
        for (auto wpID : weaponLayoutList)
        {
            char * wpName = wpID.WeaponName;
            unsigned weaponX = wpLayout.GetInt(wpName, "WEAPONHASH");
            if (!WEAPON::HAS_PED_GOT_WEAPON(playerPed, weaponX, 0))
            {
                WEAPON::GIVE_DELAYED_WEAPON_TO_PED(playerPed, weaponX, 9999, 0);
                for (auto wpCompID : weaponComponentList)
                {
                    char * wpCompoName = wpCompID.weaponComponent;
                    unsigned weaponComp = wpLayout.GetInt(wpName, wpCompoName);
                    WAIT(0);
                    if (WEAPON::DOES_WEAPON_TAKE_WEAPON_COMPONENT(weaponX, weaponComp))
                    {
                        WEAPON::GIVE_WEAPON_COMPONENT_TO_PED(playerPed, weaponX, weaponComp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Log::Msg("Files WeaponsLayout.ini loaded!");
    Notifications::MessageCentre4000("~p~Loaded~s~: Weapons Layout");
}
```

[my ini class]

```
class Ini
{
private:
    std::string inifile;
public:

    Ini(std::string file)
    {
        this->inifile = file;
    }

    void WriteString(std::string string, std::string app, std::string key)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileStringA(app.c_str(), key.c_str(), string.c_str(), this->inifile.c_str());
    }

    std::string GetString(std::string app, std::string key)
    {
        char buf[100];
        GetPrivateProfileStringA(app.c_str(), key.c_str(), "NULL", buf, 100, this->inifile.c_str());
        return (std::string)buf;
    }

    void WriteInt(int value, std::string app, std::string key)
    {
        WriteString(std::to_string(value), app, key);
    }

    int GetInt(std::string app, std::string key)
    {
        return std::stoi(GetString(app, key));
    }
}
```

DEBUG:

```
Files reading WeaponsLayout.ini!
Exception thrown at 0x000007FEFD71A06D in GTA5.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x000000013AD4E610.
The thread 0x4628 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4d78 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4cd0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3c20 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3678 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1278 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x59a0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5458 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4a8c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5300 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4b20 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x526c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x500c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4be0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x266c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x59ec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3020 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x581c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5098 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xd98 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5180 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1cc8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4c84 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x112c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2dc0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5910 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x59cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2eb4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5aec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x58cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5a94 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x481c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5554 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2358 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1b70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5764 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x53cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4ba4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4008 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x566c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x415c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4cc0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x512c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5614 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5390 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4d68 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x56e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x54e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1bc0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x55d0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4f1c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4efc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x54b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4144 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x614 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5820 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4878 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4184 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2064 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x568c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x30cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x57d8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5658 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4c94 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5084 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4ff4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5858 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x148c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x209c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x52bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5170 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1388 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xc10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x12c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xca8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2040 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4d1c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x358c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1eac has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5608 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x28d8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4c44 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5a0c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4420 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5828 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x29f4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4e60 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x54c4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4564 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x50ec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x43cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4e74 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x549c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xd74 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5b90 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4f7c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x30e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4f74 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1530 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5584 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
DXGI WARNING: Process is terminating. Using simple reporting. Please call ReportLiveObjects() at runtime for standard reporting. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING: Live Producer at 0x0000000000474EA8, Refcount: 4. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING:   Live Object at 0x0000000000488880, Refcount: 4. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING:   Live Object at 0x00000000004640E0, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING: Live                         Object :      2 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
The program '[22656] GTA5.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Might be time to learn how to use a debugger, and how to catch crashes in the debugger to locate when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: Might be time to read what I said exactly! "...so now my script what make me problems, because it search in my file for all Weapons & Weapon Components!" ps: Nobody need comments like this!!!

Comment: Coming up with an arbitrary reason for the crash is not debugging, where exactly does the crash occur and what exactly caused it? nullptr access, gabage ptr access, buffer overflow etc...?

Comment: imo, it was a constructive comment from @Someprogrammerdude. Debugging doesnt only help us identify what you mean exactly, it rather helps you solving the problem on your own.

Comment: If you provide a [MCVE] maybe wen can help you.

Comment: Being able to use a debugger, [and other debugging techinques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is a **required** skill for any programmer. One can't simply try to solve problems such as crashes by simply guessing and hoping for the best.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Agree! The opposite is true. After having spent a significant part of my life-time in debugging over the years, I became quite good to find bugs/crashs by mere guessing (at least when I wrote the code myself). This safes a lot of time (and is good to impress my colleagues). :-)

Comment: @Scheff Experience and knowledge make it less *guessing* and more *knowing* about those things. :)

Comment: To analyze a crash by eyes, a stack trace would help much. You could copy/paste it out of VS and [edit] it into your question...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have attach a debugger and already posted in my post. Ive look into [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) but idk how to fix this!  int GetInt(std::string app, std::string key)
    {
        return std::stoi(GetString(app, key));
    }

Comment: Then I suggest e.g. [this `std::stoi` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), which mentions that `std::invalid_argument` could be thrown if no conversion could be made. And considering that you attempt to convert a hexadecimal number using base 10 it's no wonder no conversion could be made.

Comment: What you added to your question was the output - not the stack trace. What I was asking for was the contents of the call stack (in German VS it is called "Aufrufliste"). It shows which function calls were nested to achieve the current code position (of break or crash) beginning from `main()` (or even before). (Sorry, that I asked for "stack trace" - this term seems to be more common in the *ix world where I worked in the ancient past.)